# How to install mysql2 gem using bundler and capistrano

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, bundler, mysql2

I'm trying to deploy a small rails3 app to a FreeBSD host using capistrano and bundler. I have added the line

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

to my deploy.rb file, and bundler seems to work fine until it comes to the mysql2 gem. Here the install fails because the install script uses `chmod` and `chgrp` to try to install the gem with root:wheel as it's owner. This fails and I'm stuck with a half installed app.

I tried to trick bundler into using the system wide version of the mysql2 gem like this:

```
group :production do
  gem 'mysql2', :path => "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.2.6"
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

But this is not allowed by bundler, and I can't leave the path in the development mode, as the setup for the development machines are completely different.

Has anybody had any luck getting the mysql2 gem work with a bundler/capistrano setup on FreeBSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your deploy.rb

default_environment['RB_USER_INSTALL'] = '/usr/bin/install -c'